# How do I make Python Structlog to log without the keyword `event`

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, structlog

I am using Python Structlog. Everything is logged as

```
event='Something Happened'
```

I don't want that event keyword and I just want the event data to be logged:

```
'Something happened'
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you use the `built in logging` given you don't need the `struct`

Comment: I use some custom processors for structlog and only at the last step(i.e. writing to file) I don't want `event`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always write an own renderer that just logs out the event without anything else:

```
>>> def renderer(logger, name, event_dict):
...     return event_dict["event"]
...
>>> import structlog
>>> structlog.configure(processors=[renderer])
>>> structlog.get_logger().msg("look, no struct!")
look, no struct!
```

Comment: How do I log to a file with PrintLogger()?

Comment: PrintLoggerFactory takes a file argument: http://www.structlog.org/en/stable/api.html#structlog.PrintLoggerFactory  – but you should really always print to stdout and redirect it somewhere.  That’s much more flexible.